# How to utilize SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR in InitializeObjectAttributes()

Tags: c++, c, windows, delphi, winapi

Could someone provide me an example of utilizing SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR in [InitializeObjectAttributes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547804%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)? I plan to use them with NtCreateKey(). I couldn't find any example on the Internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on the security descriptor you *need*. What are you trying to do? e.g. why NtCreateKey, not RegCreateKeyEx?

Comment: I'm creating a registry and file-system snapshot program, just want to see if using NT Native API could tweak the scanning speed.The purpose of my SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR question is ... to decide whether

Comment: I'm creating a registry and file-system snapshot program, just want to see if using NT Native API could tweak the scanning speed.The purpose of my SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR question is to decide whether security descriptor should be included as parameter in my own RegCreateKey method, if there is a good example/explanation how to use it.

Comment: About the security descriptor I need, any of SD that someone could give a good example code. I just want to see the implementation of the documentation in real code.

Comment: BTW, my own RegCreateKey method is not related with creating a registry snapshot program. It is just to make the method works for general use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of `InitializeObjectAttributes()` can be just well documented [SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379563.aspx). You can use for example `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor` to convert [Security Descriptor String Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379570.aspx) to [SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379563.aspx). You can create [SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379563.aspx) without usage of [security descriptor definition language (SDDL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379567.aspx).

Comment: @Oleg: I have the very same problem here, but i need to include wdm.h and therefore ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor will not be defined since wdm.h defines "_NTDDK_" that excludes the definition in sddl.h. Do you have any clue how to solve that? Thanks

Comment: @schoetbi: Do you have any problems if you included `sddl.h` from the `C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api`? Which version of DDK you use? By the way you should include `sddl.h` also explicitly in the most cases if you use Windows SDK.

Comment: @Oleg: I include sddl.h but the definition for ConvertSS...Descr... is not active since the macro _NTDDK_ is defined(line 207). winddkVer=7600.16385.1. If I include sddl.h before ntddk.h it works but then I get errors since WINAPI is not defined. If I then include wtypes.h beforehead then I get _PROCESSOR_NUMBER redefinition. No idea what order is the correct one.

Comment: @schoetbi: OK, now I see. Do you tried to include The lines which defines `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW` and `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor` directly in your code? What kind of software you develop? Is it kernel or user mode driver?

Comment: @Oleg: Yes I tried but then I got LNK2019 unresolved external symbol: _ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorA@16. After linking with advapi32.lib this still exists. Its a Kernel mode driver.

Comment: @schoetbi: I don't used DDK since a long time. It's strange that you used `_ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorA` instead of `_ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW`. Do you defined `UNICODE`?

Comment: @Oleg: I use the ddk because of a third party product. The problem is not relevant for me any more since I now use a completely other method to communicate with the driver. I now use Ioctls. Thank you for your help!.